# Apache Ignite repository save method is doing only UPDATE instead of INSERT

Tags: spring, spring-data, ignite, impala, apacheignite

I'm developing a Spring Boot + Impala app using Apache Ignite as cache store.
The problem is `IgniteRepository.save(key,entity)` is only running UPDATE query instead of INSERT.

pom.xml

```
<ignite.version>2.14.0</ignite.version>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-spring-data-ext</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
    <version>${ignite.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-indexing</artifactId>
    <version>${ignite.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
    <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
    <version>${ignite.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Ignite Configuration :

```
IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
        cfg.setIgniteInstanceName("springDataNode");
        cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);

CacheConfiguration ccfg = new CacheConfiguration("XYZCache");
    ccfg.setIndexedTypes(Long.class, XYZ.class);
    ccfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
    ccfg.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC);
    ccfg.setReadThrough(true);
    ccfg.setWriteThrough(true);
    ccfg.setWriteBehindEnabled(true);

    CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory<Long, XYZ> factory = new CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory<>();
    factory.setDataSourceBean("ImpalaDataSource");

    JdbcType jdbcType = new JdbcType();
    jdbcType.setCacheName("XYZCache");
    jdbcType.setKeyType(Long.class);
    jdbcType.setValueType(XYZ.class);
    jdbcType.setDatabaseTable("schema.table");

    jdbcType.setKeyFields(new JdbcTypeField(Types.BIGINT, "id", Long.class, "id"));
    jdbcType.setValueFields(
            new JdbcTypeField(Types.VARCHAR, "comments", String.class, "comments"),
            new JdbcTypeField(Types.BIGINT, "id", Long.class, "id")
            );
    factory.setTypes(jdbcType);
    ccfg.setCacheStoreFactory(factory);

    cfg.setCacheConfiguration(ccfg);
    return IgniteSpring.start(cfg, applicationContext);
```

Ignite Repository :

```
@RepositoryConfig(cacheName = "XYZCache")
public interface XYZRepository extends IgniteRepository<XYZ, Long> {

    @Query("select * FROM XYZ WHERE comments=?")
    List<XYZ> test(String comments);

    @Query("insert into XYZ (id,comments) values (?,?)")
    List<XYZ> customSave(Long id,String comments);

}
```

POJO :

```
@Data
public class XYZ implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2677636393779376050L;
    
    @QuerySqlField
    private Long id;
    @QuerySqlField
    private String comments;
}
```

Calling code:

```
xyzRepository.save(id, xyz);
xyzRepository.customSave(id, comments);
```

Both the methods are throwing error by running **UPDATE** query (instead of **INSERT**) which is not supported in Impala and also not what I intend to do :

> Caused by:
> org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CachePartialUpdateCheckedException:
> Failed to update keys (retry update if possible).: [1671548234688]  at
> org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheUtils.convertToCacheException(GridCacheUtils.java:1251)
> ~[ignite-core-2.14.0.jar:2.14.0]
>
> Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed update
> entry in database [table=schema.table, entry=Entry [key=1671548234688,
> val=pkg.XYZ [idHash=1354181174, hash=991365654, id=1671548234688,
> comments=test]]]          at
> org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.put(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:593)
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheMapEntry$AtomicCacheUpdateClosure.update(GridCacheMapEntry.java:6154)
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheMapEntry$AtomicCacheUpdateClosure.call(GridCacheMapEntry.java:5918)
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheMapEntry$AtomicCacheUpdateClosure.call(GridCacheMapEntry.java:5603)
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree$Invoke.invokeClosure(BPlusTree.java:4254)
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree$Invoke.access$5700(BPlusTree.java:4148)
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree.invokeDown(BPlusTree.java:2226)
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.BPlusTree.invoke(BPlusTree.java:2116)
> ... 146 common frames omitted
> Caused by: javax.cache.integration.CacheWriterException: Failed update entry in database [table=schema.table, entry=Entry
> [key=1671548234688, val=pkg.XYZ [idHash=1354181174, hash=991365654,
> id=1671548234688, comments=test]]]
> at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.CacheAbstractJdbcStore.writeUpsert(CacheAbstractJdbcStore.java:978)
> at org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.CacheAbstractJdbcStore.write(CacheAbstractJdbcStore.java:1029)
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.put(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:585)
> ... 153 common frames omitted
>
> Caused by: com.cloudera.impala.support.exceptions.GeneralException:
> [Cloudera]ImpalaJDBCDriver ERROR processing query/statement.
> Error Code: 0, SQL state: TStatus(statusCode:ERROR_STATUS,
> sqlState:HY000, errorMessage:AnalysisException: Impala does not
> support modifying a non-Kudu table: schema.table ), Query: UPDATE
> `schema`.`table` SET `table`.`comments` = 'test' WHERE (`table`.`id` =
> 1671548234688).           ... 163 common frames omitted

What is the issue here? Why UPDATE is being forced by Apache Ignite? How can I change this behavior?

**I also implemented Persistable interface and overrode isNew() to return true but it didn't work.**

PS: Select queries are working fine (findAll, findById etc.) including the custom **test()** method. So, there is no datasource configuration issue and I am able to connect to Impala.

Comment: try to implement your own cachestore: https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/datagrid/store/jdbc/CacheJdbcPersonStore.java

see what happens. I would also test it without the Ignite Repository

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because the [dialect](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/store/jdbc/dialect/JdbcDialect.html) you are using does not have the merge set up.
See [here](https://github.com/gridgain/gridgain/blob/39469c6df0c41cfebfafcac9f68fa23746a17ab3/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/cache/store/jdbc/CacheAbstractJdbcStore.java#L998): to understand the flow. This is per the stack trace you posted.

```
org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.CacheAbstractJdbcStore.writeUpsert(CacheAbstractJdbcStore.java:978) at  <br>
org.apache.ignite.cache.store.jdbc.CacheAbstractJdbcStore.write(CacheAbstractJdbcStore.java:1029) at <br>
org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.store.GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.put(GridCacheStoreManagerAdapter.java:585) ..
```

Alternatively, you can [write your own data store factory](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/examples/datagrid/store/jdbc/CacheJdbcPersonStore.java).

Comment: logs - o.a.i.c.store.jdbc.CacheJdbcPojoStore    : Failed to resolve dialect (BasicJdbcDialect will be used): Impala
Thanks for pointing it out, let me write my own datastore factory and see !